# OOP Web-scraper w/ Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, http, beautifulsoup

This is my first major web scraping program in python. My code works nonetheless, I'm just not sure if it's the best OOP design. My code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import argparse
import sys


class ComicScraper():  # Class ComicScraper for scraping comic books
    def __init__(self, comic_titles, comic_prices, all_comics):
        self.comic_titles = comic_titles
        self.comic_prices = comic_prices
        self.all_comics = all_comics
        # url of comicbook site
        self.url = 'https://leagueofcomicgeeks.com/comics/new-comics/2020/'
        self.webpage = requests.get(self.url)  # HTTP request for url
        # BeautifulSoup object of webpage
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.webpage.content, 'html.parser')
        self.titles = list(
            map(BeautifulSoup.get_text, self.soup.find_all('div', class_='comic-title')))
        self.comicinfo = [x.replace(u'\xa0', u'').strip()
                          for x in list(map(BeautifulSoup.get_text, self.soup.find_all('div', class_='comic-details comic-release')))
                          ]
        self.prices = [
            prices[-5:] if prices[-5:].startswith('$') else 'No price' for prices in self.comicinfo]

    def main(self):
        if len(sys.argv) == 1:
            print("###### New Comics ######")
            for title, info in zip(self.titles, self.comicinfo):
                print(title, '--->', info)
        if self.all_comics:
            print("###### New Comics ######")
            for titles, info in zip(self, titles, self.comicinfo):
                print(title, '--->', info)
        if self.comic_titles and self.comic_prices:
            print("###### New Comics ######")
            for title, prices in zip(self.titles, self.prices):
                print(title, '--->', info)
        if self.comic_titles:
            for comic_title in self.comic_titles:
                print(comic_title)
        if self.comic_prices:
            for dol_amount in comic_prices:
                print(dol_amount)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # Titles of comicbooks i.e "Detective Comics #1"
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--titles', help='Print comic titles ONLY', dest='titles')
    # Scrape prices of comic books in order
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--prices', help='Get comic prices ONLY', dest='prices')

    parser.add_argument('-a', '--all', help='Get titles, prices, publisher, and descriptions',
                        dest='all_comics', action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    scraper = ComicScraper(args.titles, args.prices, args.all_comics)
    scraper.main()
```

I have some doubts about how much instance variables I've used? Would refactoring this code as a bunch of functions be the best way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Bugs

Lines 32 and 42:

```
        for titles, info in zip(self, titles, self.comicinfo):


        for dol_amount in comic_prices:
```

both have unresolved variable references - `titles` and `comic_prices`.

### Bare class declaration

```
class ComicScraper():  # Class ComicScraper for scraping comic books
```

can be

```
class ComicScraper:
    """
    For scraping comic books
    """
```

Note the more common format for docstrings used.

### Doing too much in an `init`

```
requests.get(self.url)
```

should probably not be done in an `__init__`. Constructors are usually best to initialize everything that the class will need without "doing" too much.

### Argument names

`titles` doesn't actually accept multiple titles; it only accepts one. Providing the argument twice overwrites the first value. That means that this loop:

```
        for comic_title in self.comic_titles:
```

is actually going to loop through each of the characters in the provided string, which is probably not what you want.

Reading the docs - https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html - you probably want `action='append'`.

### Reaching past `argparse`

This:

```
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
```

should not be done. Instead, rely on the output of `argparse`.

### Suggested

Here is a re-thought program:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
from datetime import date, datetime
from typing import Iterable
import argparse
import re
from requests import Session


class Comic:
    # ·  Apr 8th, 2020  ·  $7.99
    RELEASE_PAT = re.compile(
        r'^\s*·\s*'
        r'(?P<month>\S+)\s*'
        r'(?P<day>\d+)\w*?,\s*'
        r'(?P<year>\d+)\s*'
        r'(·\s*\$(?P<price>[0-9.]+))?\s*$'
    )

    def __init__(self, item: Tag):
        self.id = int(item['id'].split('-')[1])
        sku = item.select_one('.comic-diamond-sku')
        if sku:
            self.sku: str = sku.text.strip()
        else:
            self.sku = None

        consensus_head = item.find(name='span', text=re.compile('CONSENSUS:'))
        if consensus_head:
            self.consensus = float(consensus_head.find_next_sibling().strong.text)
        else:
            self.consensus = None

        potw_head = item.find(name='span', text=re.compile('POTW'))
        self.pick_of_the_week = float(potw_head.find_next_sibling().text.rstrip('%'))

        title_anchor = item.select_one('.comic-title > a')
        self.title: str = title_anchor.text
        self.link = title_anchor['href']

        details = item.select_one('.comic-details')
        self.publisher: str = details.strong.text

        parts = self.RELEASE_PAT.match(list(details.strings)[2]).groupdict()
        self.pub_date: date = (
            datetime.strptime(
                f'{parts["year"]}-{parts["month"]}-{parts["day"]}',
                '%Y-%b-%d'
            )
            .date()
        )
        price = parts.get('price')
        if price is None:
            self.price = price
        else:
            self.price = float(price)

        self.desc: str = list(item.select_one('.comic-description > p').strings)[0]


class ComicScraper:
    URL = 'https://leagueofcomicgeeks.com/'

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = Session()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.session.close()

    @staticmethod
    def _parse(content: str) -> Iterable[Comic]:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
        list_items = soup.select('#comic-list > ul > li')
        return (Comic(li) for li in list_items)

    def get_from_page(self) -> Iterable[Comic]:
        with self.session.get(self.URL + 'comics/new-comics') as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            return self._parse(response.content)

    def get_from_xhr(self, req_date: date) -> Iterable[Comic]:
        params = {
            'addons': 1,
            'list': 'releases',
            'list_option': '',
            'list_refinement': '',
            'date_type': 'week',
            'date': f'{req_date:%d/%m/%Y}',
            'date_end': '',
            'series_id': '',
            'user_id': 0,
            'title': '',
            'view': 'list',
            'format[]': (1, 6),
            'character': '',
            'order': 'pulls',
        }
        with self.session.get(self.URL + 'comic/get_comics', params=params) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            return self._parse(response.json()['list'])


def print_comics(comics: Iterable[Comic]):
    print(f'{"Title":40} {"Publisher":20} {"Date":10} {"Price":6}')

    for c in comics:
        print(
            f'{c.title[:40]:40} {c.publisher[:20]:20} '
            f'{c.pub_date}', end=' '
        )
        if c.price is not None:
            print(f' ${c.price:5.2f}', end='')
        print()


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # Titles of comicbooks i.e "Detective Comics #1"
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--titles', help='Print these comic titles ONLY',
                        action='append')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    titles = args.titles and set(args.titles)

    with ComicScraper() as scraper:
        comics = scraper.get_from_xhr(date(year=2020, month=3, day=25))
        if titles:
            comics = (c for c in comics if c.title in titles)
        print_comics(comics)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Points:

- Your original class is not useful as a class - it's effectively a function; the important stuff to capture in a class is distinct fields on the data you're trying to represent
- You can still class-ify the generator as a class method
- Use type hints
- Use set membership check for titles
- Use a regex to parse the info field
- Pull out price and date as a float and date, respectively; don't leave them stringly-typed

Note the second method to use an XHR backend instead of the web front-end. The return format is awkward - they return rendered HTML as a part of the JSON payload - but the interface is more powerful and the method might be more efficient. I have not done a lot of investigation into what each of those parameters means; to learn more you will probably have to dig around the site using developer tools.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it’s much appreciated!  I just have a few questions: What does “Iterable” do?Which is better parsing with re or BeautifulSoup?

Comment: _What does “Iterable” do?_ It's a type hint that gives a promise for the type to be - literally - an iterable of a certain element type. It does not make promises about the ability to call `len`, or mutability, or durability.

Comment: _Which is better parsing with re or BeautifulSoup?_ Generally BS if you can, but sometimes that's not enough and semantic information is mixed into a single string, in which case regexes can help.

Comment: Edited for narrower, better-structured use of BS tree navigation.

Comment: So, “Iterable” is just a sanity check to make sure that the argument passed is a iterable, am I right?

Comment: Basically, yes. However, no runtime checks are performed - it's up to external tools like your IDE.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you explain how the print_comics() function works; I see that there is an f-string but I can't see where the "Title", "Publisher", "Date", and "Price" values come from. Likewise, it don't understand the numbers beside those values. Sorry, I don't mean to bombard you with questions, much thanks in advance!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106566/discussion-between-reinderien-and-practical1).

Answer (score 3):

Just one small contribution from me: I think your utilization of BeautifulSoup is not optimal. For example this bit of code is wasteful as it does not warrant using the `map` function:

```
self.titles = list(
    map(BeautifulSoup.get_text, self.soup.find_all('div', class_='comic-title')))
```

What does the map function do ? From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) (emphasis is mine):

> map(function, iterable, ...)
>
> Return an iterator that **applies function to every item of iterable**, yielding the results. If additional iterable arguments are
>   passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the
>   items from all iterables in parallel. With multiple iterables, the
>   iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted...

A more straightforward of getting the same result (and trimming text) would be:

```
self.titles = [title.get_text().strip() for title in self.soup.find_all('div', class_='comic-title')]
```

Or:

```
self.titles = [title.get_text(strip=True) for title in self.soup.find_all('div', class_='comic-title')]
```

And there is no need to involve `BeautifulSoup.get_text` either. You've already loaded the soup, once is enough.

Another thing:

```
self.comicinfo = [x.replace(u'\xa0', u'').strip()
                  for x in list(map(BeautifulSoup.get_text, self.soup.find_all('div', class_='comic-details comic-release')))
                  ]
```

Here you are trying to get rid of the [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) 
Although we are dealing we just one pesky character you might encounter more unwanted 'characters' in the future when scraping UTF-8 encoded pages.

Based on several posts like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58692697/6843158) and [this one](https://towardsdatascience.com/difference-between-nfd-nfc-nfkd-and-nfkc-explained-with-python-code-e2631f96ae6c) a possible strategy is to use the [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) function to derive canonical representations of those strings. Since the closest representation of a non-breaking space is of course a plain space, then we want a plain space.

In short this will give a cleaned-up string that is more usable:

```
unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", 'Archie Comics·\xa0 Apr 8th, 2020 \xa0·\xa0 $7.99')

# output: 'Archie Comics·  Apr 8th, 2020  ·  $7.99'
```

(and there using the map function makes sense I think)

The cost is importing one more dependency: `import unicodedata`
Admittedly that is not so easy to grasp and even experienced developers are having headaches with processing of Unicode text and character set conversions. But you can't really avoid those issues when doing scraping jobs, they will always torment you.

One more reference on the topic: [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)